# Usage of crutch when referred to avoid

Tags: metaphors, books

Recently, while going through a book I encounter this statement.

- Try to avoid the crutch of saying "I feel like." As in, "I feel like you are being mean to me."

I am trying to get the exact meaning this line wants to offer, but can only find online references of `being crutch` meaning `someone giving support`. Unable to decode this statement with the same.

Any kind of help here, please?

Comment: Just as a crutch is an aid to a crippled leg, but not as good, a metaphorical "crutch" in this sense is an extra phrase that acts as a clumsy substitute for something that could be said more simply and clearly in fewer words.

Comment: You're using "I feel like XXX" as a "crutch" -- a phrase to "prop up" your expression.

Comment: The book is saying it's better to get to your point: "You are being mean to me." Don't hide behind *I feel like*.

Comment: Thanks, Folks, I think now I am able to get it... closing this thread and accepting an answer too which was most close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Ece English](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/what-are-crutch-words)* says, about 'crutch phrases':

> A crutch is a stick you put under your arm to help you walk if you have injured your leg. Basically, a crutch is something you use for support, but you don't have to have had an injury to use a crutch word.
>
> When we want to give ourselves more time to think or to emphasize a point, we use crutch words; they support us when we are speaking.
>
> It's important to remember that although crutch words can help when we're thinking of what to say next, you should be aware that people find over-use of them very annoying; people dislike hearing too many crutch words.
>
> Crutch words can be used in casual conversation but should be avoided in formal settings like public speaking or presentations. Crutch words are not generally used in written English.

Presumably, 'I feel like' is being discouraged because of the fact that it lessens the force of your conviction; rather than asserting it, you're giving the other person an opening to write it off. This sense is also present (more generally) in dictionaries:

> a source or means of support or assistance that is relied on heavily or excessively ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crutch))

Answer (score 0):

[As Cambridge states](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crutch), the word "crutch" can mean:

> something that provides help and support and that you depend on, often too much